# Problema al filtrar un "pedido" con Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

Buenas tardes a todos,

Estoy haciendo un filtro con Eloquent que básicamente analiza 3 campos, que en esos 3 campos, cada uno es independiente del otro y no tienen por que estar los 3 especificados.

Los campos son "Modalidad" -> (Alquiler/Compra)
"Habitaciones_min" -> (Numero minimo de habitaciones del inmueble de 0 a 7 generalmente)
"Habitaciones_max" -> (Número maximo de habitaciones del inmueble de 1 a 7 generalmente)

He estado viendo y lo he hecho con "QueryScopes", que los he declarado en el modelo que se encarga de la tabla correspondiente "Pedidos"

**Estos son mis scopes en el modelo "Pedido"**

```
public function scopeModalidad($query, $modalidad){
    if($modalidad)
        return $query->where('modalidad', '=', $modalidad);
}

public function scopeHabitacionesMin($query, $habitaciones_min){
    if($habitaciones_min)
        return $query->where('habitaciones_min', '=', $habitaciones_min);
}

public function scopeHabitacionesMax($query, $habitaciones_max){
    if($habitaciones_max)
        return $query->where('habitaciones_max', '=', $habitaciones_max);
}
```

** Mi formulario **

```
<form action="{{ route('pedido.filter') }}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label style="font-size:16px">Modalidad</label>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="filter-modal-alquiler" name="modalidad" value="Alquiler">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                                Alquiler
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="filter-modal-compra" name="modalidad" value="Compra">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                                Compra
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label style="font-size:15.6px">Hab min</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="numero-habitaciones-min">
                                            <option value="null">No filtrar</option>
                                            @for($i=0; $i<=8; $i++)
                                                <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                                            @endfor
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label style="font-size:15.6px">Hab max</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="numero-habitaciones-max">
                                            <option value="null">No filtrar</option>
                                            @for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++)
                                                <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                                            @endfor
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <label style="font-size:15.6px">Busca por teléfono</label>
                                        <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:4px;">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class="input-group-text">+34</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="telefono">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

** Y mi controlador **

```
public function filtrar(Request $request){
    $modalidad = $request->get("modalidad");
    $request->get("numero-habitaciones-min") != "null" ? $habitaciones_min = $request->get("numero-habitaciones-min") : $habitaciones_min = "";
    $request->get("numero-habitaciones-max") != "null" ? $habitaciones_max = $request->get("numero-habitaciones-max") : $habitaciones_max = "";
    $telefono = $request->get("telefono");

    $pedidos_f = Pedido::select("*")
        ->modalidad($modalidad)
        ->habitacionesmin($habitaciones_min)
        ->habitacionesmax($habitaciones_max)
        ->get();

}
```

Parece que funciona correctamente, el problema es que sí en habitaciones_min el valor es 0, se me descuadra todo... no se por qué

Me da valores que son incorrectos,

Ejemplo pongo solamente el filtro de "modalidad" Alquiler ( Que en la bbdd hay 30 reigstros solamente ), de los cuales esta dividido en alquiler / compra, y al elegir las habitaciones mínimas, sea cual sea el valor me devuelve 30..

Luego si habitaciones_min es 0 , lo ponga con el valor que sea, siempre da datos erroneos, luego en la bbdd hago las mismas querys y dan valores muy diferentes.

Sabrían por que puede pasar esto? He comprobado que lo que recibo por el input es un "0" , y que luego ami se me muestran resultados con "2" o "5"..

Gracias

**Actualizacion: He intentado cambiar los inputs aver si ese era el problema, he puesto input type number, asi que por defalt si no se escoge nada devuelve null, pero sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema, parece que si pongo 0, me devuelve todos los resultados, y en ese campo hay varios numeros ...**

**Parece que de alguna forma los "0" me dan errores , si hay ese valor devuelve todos los resultados, me pasa tambien con habitaciones_max,.. de momento he quitado el 0 y he puesto un 1 como mínimo.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Controlador**

Primeramente, puedes asignar los valores de los inputs de los filtros a sus respectivas variables directamente, sin esos condicionales. Para el caso que no se haya ingresado un valor para algún filtro, a la variable se asignará el valor `null`.

```
$habitaciones_min = $request->input("numero-habitaciones-min");
$habitaciones_max = $request->input("numero-habitaciones-max");
$modalidad = $request->modalidad;
$telefono = $request->telefono;
```

Luego, para la consulta puedes usar [Cláusulas condicionales](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) para aplicar un scope si el valor del input correspondiente resulta en verdadero. Esto funciona como un `if` por lo que `null`, `0` o un `string` vacío resultarán en `false`, y la condición no se cumplirá. Entonces, para que un filtro con valor `0` resulte en `true`, puedes agregarle un [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), que determina si una variable está definida y no es `null`, de esa manera cuando la variable valga `0`, el isset devolverá `true` y la cláusula condicional se ejecutará.

```
$pedidos_f = Pedido::when($modalidad, function ($query) use ($modalidad) {
        $query->modalidad($modalidad);
    })
    ->when(isset($habitaciones_min), function ($query) use ($habitaciones_min) {
        $query->habitacionesmin($habitaciones_min);
    })
    ->when(isset($habitaciones_max), function ($query) use ($habitaciones_max) {
        $query->habitacionesmax($habitaciones_max);
    })
    ->get();
```

**Modelo Pedido**

Finalmente, al usar esas cláusulas condicionales en la consulta, no es necesario que pongas condicionales `if` en tus scopes.

```
public function scopeModalidad($query, $modalidad){
    return $query->where('modalidad', $modalidad);
}

public function scopeHabitacionesMin($query, $habitaciones_min){
    return $query->where('habitaciones_min', $habitaciones_min);
}

public function scopeHabitacionesMax($query, $habitaciones_max){
    return $query->where('habitaciones_max', $habitaciones_max);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema es que en los métodos no estás devolviendo un objeto cuando el valor recibido por parámetro está vacío y te explico:

```
$pedidos_f = Pedido::select("*")
    ->modalidad($modalidad) // Si modalidad es cadena vacía
    ->habitacionesmin($habitaciones_min) // No es posible ejecutar esto
    ->habitacionesmax($habitaciones_max)
    ->get();
```

De acuerdo al [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes):

> Scopes should always return a query builder instance

Solo asegúrate de que cada método siempre devuelva el objeto:

```
public function scopeModalidad($query, $modalidad){
    if($modalidad)
        return $query->where('modalidad', '=', $modalidad);
    // Siempre debes devolver $query
    return $query;
}

public function scopeHabitacionesMin($query, $habitaciones_min){
    if($habitaciones_min)
        return $query->where('habitaciones_min', '=', $habitaciones_min);
    return $query;
}

public function scopeHabitacionesMax($query, $habitaciones_max){
    if($habitaciones_max)
        return $query->where('habitaciones_max', '=', $habitaciones_max);
    return $query;
}
```