# Laravel - Controlador para poder filtrar por 2 parámetros

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-8, laravel-7

Tengo este controlador en laravel que me devuelve objetos del modelo customer, mi idea es poder aplicar 2 filtros de busqueda "name" y "email" si le paso los parametros por query string solo me aplica uno de ellos pero no los dos.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $customers = Customer::all();


    if($request->has('name')) {
        $customers = Customer::where('name', 'LIKE', "%".$request->get('name')."%");
    }

    if($request->has('email')) {
        $customers = Customer::where('email', 'LIKE', "%".$request->get('email')."%");
    }


    return $customers->paginate(100);

}
```

## Hago una llamada con postman de este tipo

api-devel.local/api/customers/?email=yahoo.com&name=grupo

Comment: ¿Y siempre van a llegar los 2 valores o se dará el caso de que alguno no exté presente en el *request*?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al filtrar un "pedido" con Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/451704/problema-al-filtrar-un-pedido-con-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de query scopes te adjunto la documentación oficial https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes.

en tu modelo creas algo parecido a esto.
que va a evaluar si encuentra alguna coincidencia con el email.

debes agregarle siempre al inicio (scope) seguido del nombre con la primera letra mayuscula.

```
  public function scopeEmail($query,$busqueda)
    {
        return $query->where('email', 'like', '%'.$busqueda.'%');
    }
```

y luego creas otro scope para el name

```
public function scopeName($query,$busqueda)
        {
            return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$busqueda.'%');
        }
```

al tener esto creado en el modelo, podrás hacer lo siguiente en tu controlador

```
$customers = Customer::email($request->get('email'))->name($request->get('name'))->paginate(100);
```

en el caso que solo llegue el name solo te retornará los datos con coincidan con el name, en el caso que le pases solo el email solo retornará las coincidencias con el email y en caso que le pases los 2 te retornara todas las coincidencias con el email y name que le pasastes.